# Why do these two formulas give me the exact same incorrect value?

Tags: excel, math, error-handling, arithmetic-expressions, calculation

I have an excel document in which the cells AE61, AE62, and AE63 have the values 9.97551241928828000 x 10^(-1), 3.82933360922740 x 10^(-4), and
2.065824710241100 x 10^(-3), respectively. I'm wondering why, when I type the formula ((AE62/AE61)/(0.00038/0.99757)-1)*1000 into AE77, and type the formula ((AE63/AE61)/(0.00205/0.99757)-1)*1000 into AE78, I get the value 7.738320123873 *in both cells*, even though according to Wolfram Alpha we have:

((0.000382933361/0.997551241928)/(0.00038/0.99757)-1)*1000=7.738320327338977213...

and

((0.002065824710/0.997551241928)/(0.00205/0.99757)-1)*1000=7.738320006408680641...,

which both are not equal and don't equal 7.738320123873.

Comment: I get different results: see my answer. Which version of Excel are you using and on which operating system?

Comment: Related: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic

Comment: @RoryDaulton, it's Excel 15.32 on a mac with OS X version 10.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Excel stores numbers in IEEE754 64-bit. This format has ~16 significant digits. But the numbers you listed has less. For example, 0.000382933361 has only 9 significant digits. I suppose, that this number has been rounded for printing. It can be (for example) as low as 0.0003829333605001, and can be as high as 0.0003829333614999. This inaccuracy can affect the final result.

If I substitute a lower bound/higher bound number for AE62, and AE63 (which get rounded to the numbers you listed), I can get the result you've shown:

- AE77 can be between [7.738319014156225251;7.738321640521350631]
- AE78 can be between [7.738319762989220862;7.738320249827568276]

Both intervals contain the number excel calculates, 7.738320123873.

So, all in all, if you can print numbers in greater precision (not rounded to 12 decimal places, but to have at least 17 significant digits), I'm sure you'll find that Excel actually calculates your formula precisely.

Comment: I had listed all numbers only to twelve decimal places, but now when I change the values used in the calculation to eighteen decimal places and re-type in the formulas I seem to still get them same thing. Any thoughts as to why this may be?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the updated numbers? Note that 17 significant digits are needed. Best would be if you could print the numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: Actually I see a difference in the cells now, they're 7.738320123182870000 and 7.738320123182650000.

Answer (score 3):

In my Excel version 1706 in Office 365 on Windows 10 Home 64 bit running on an AMD A8-5500 CPU I get:

for cell AE77, `7.7383203273389`;

for cell AE78, `7.73832000604851`.

These are very close to the results from Wolfram Alpha, to about 14 significant digits. MS Excel uses the "double" type--floating point values stored in 8 bytes, which can store 15 to 16 significant digits. Each operation can lose significant digits, sometimes up to one significant digit per operation. Some operations like subtraction can lose even more, and I see you have subtraction in each of your calculations. So my Excel is as close as can be expected.

If you need better precision, use a computer language or software with extended-precision floating point values. For example, Python has the `decimal` module, where you can extend the precision to any finite number of digits. I do not know Wolfram Alpha's precision. When I use Python's `decimal` with its default 30 decimal places, I get

for AE77, `7.738320327338786254453768000`;

for AE78, `7.738320006408585382386216000`.

You can ignore the three trailing zeros in each of those results, which come from the final multiplication by `1000`. I note with interest that these differ from the Wolfram Alpha results.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Calculations that round or cut off and lose significant digits does seem like a reasonable explanation, but then doesn't it seem strange that the two numbers were the same up to so many decimal places? In fact, when I view them up to the 10^(-18)ths place, I see 7.738320123873430000 for both (and the 0s just keep repeating after that). If rounding in calculations is the cause, it seems strange that the values would be the same up to that many decimal places (and both wrong), especially because, as you've shown, the correct values begin to differ in the 10^(-7)ths place

Comment: @Rasputin: Yes, that is strange. Our setups are too different to tell the cause for our different results and I don't know the Mac well. Some intermediate calculations in your two cells must be equal--perhaps the precision was reduced to the "single" type which uses only 4 bytes and has fewer significant digits.